# Replacement of a mached element in an array, Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
function replaceById(requests, request) {
    requests.splice(_.indexOf(requests, _.find(requests, {id: request.id})), 1, request);
}
```

Is there any method provided by Lodash (or another utility library) to simplify replacement of a specific element `request` in an array `requests` by a predicate like

```
function(r) { return _.eq(r.id, request.id); }
```

or an identity object like

```
{id: request.id}
```

Comment: `_.find + _.index == _.findIndex` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [**findIndex**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex):

```
function replaceById(requests, request) {
  var index = _.findIndex(requests, function(r) { 
    return r.id === request.id 
  });
  requests.splice(index, 1, request);
}
```

```js
function replaceById(requests, request) {
  var index = _.findIndex(requests, function(r) { 
    return r.id === request.id 
  });
  requests.splice(index, 1, request);
}

var requests = [{id: 1, msg: 'cool'}, {id: 2, msg: 'wow'}];
replaceById(requests, {id: 2, msg: 'stuff'});
console.log(requests);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```